# Get sum for each 5 minute time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

### Problem Description

I have a table (`#tmstmp`) with 2 columns `dt` (`DATETIME`) and `payload` (`INT`). Eventually I want to sum `payload` for each 5 minute interval there is.

### Code

#### Setup

```sql
DECLARE @start DATETIME = N'2024-1-1 12:00:00';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmstmp
                     , #numbers;
CREATE TABLE #tmstmp (
  dt DATETIME PRIMARY KEY
  , payload INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #numbers (
  n INT PRIMARY KEY
);
WITH numbers (n) AS (
  SELECT 0 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS n
    FROM numbers
   WHERE n < 100
)
INSERT
  INTO #numbers
SELECT n
  FROM numbers;

WITH rnd (mins, secs) AS (
  SELECT n2.n AS mins
         , CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 60 AS INT) AS mins
   FROM #numbers AS n1
        , #numbers as n2
  WHERE n1.n < 5
    AND n2.n < 15
), tmstmp (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, secs, DATEADD(MINUTE, mins, @start)) AS dt
    FROM rnd
) 
INSERT  
  INTO #tmstmp
SELECT DISTINCT dt
       , -1 AS payload
  FROM tmstmp
 ORDER BY dt;

UPDATE #tmstmp
   SET payload = CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 AS INT);
GO
```

#### Non overlapping timeslots are easy

```sql
DECLARE @start DATETIME = N'2024-1-1 12:00:00';
DECLARE @slotDuration INT = 5;

WITH agg (slot, sum_payload) AS (
  SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, dt) / @slotDuration AS slot
         , SUM(payload) AS sum_payload
    FROM #tmstmp
   GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, dt) / @slotDuration
)
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, slot * @slotDuration, @start) AS [from]
       , DATEADD(MINUTE, (slot + 1) * @slotDuration, @start) AS [to]
       , sum_payload
  FROM agg;
```

| from | to | sum_payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 12:00:00 | 2024-01-01 12:05:00 | 124 |
| 2024-01-01 12:05:00 | 2024-01-01 12:10:00 | 106 |
| 2024-01-01 12:10:00 | 2024-01-01 12:15:00 | 95 |

#### Ultimate Goal: get running timeslots

I want, however, to have an entry for **each** interval in the range, that is from `12:00-12:05`, `12:01-12:06`, `12:02-12:07` etc. until the last timeslot.

I can construct the limits in the whole range before and use that in a `JOIN` like this:

```sql
DECLARE @start DATETIME = N'2024-1-1 12:00:00';
DECLARE @slotDuration INT = 5;
DECLARE @intervals INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, MAX(dt)) FROM #tmstmp);

WITH ranges ([from], [to], slot) AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, n, @start) AS [from]
         , DATEADD(MINUTE, n + @slotDuration, @start) AS [to]
         , n AS slot
    FROM #numbers
   WHERE n <= @intervals
), tm_mult (slot, [from], [to], dt, payload) AS (
  SELECT slot
         , [from]
         , [to]
         , dt
         , payload
    FROM #tmstmp
   INNER JOIN ranges
      ON [from] <= dt
     AND dt < [to]
)
SELECT MIN([from]) AS [from]
       , MAX([to]) AS [to]
       , SUM(payload) AS sum_payload
  FROM tm_mult
 GROUP BY slot
 ORDER BY slot;
```

| from | to | sum_payload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 12:00:00 | 2024-01-01 12:05:00 | 124 |
| 2024-01-01 12:01:00 | 2024-01-01 12:06:00 | 120 |
| 2024-01-01 12:02:00 | 2024-01-01 12:07:00 | 125 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2024-01-01 12:14:00 | 2024-01-01 12:19:00 | 19 |

While this works in this toy example I have hundreds of thousands of timestamps in my real data and worst of all I little impact on the indices. My gut feeling tells me that I will create quite some duplication with my inequality `JOIN` and I was wondering whether this is anyways the canonical way of doing it or whether there is a more `SQL-onic` way of doing it? (like the `pythonistas` like to call certain code `pythonic` if it uses the language inherent concepts rather than trying to solve it with general tools).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window functions in sql ([WINDOW - microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-window-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) / [OVER - microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) are a great asset to add to your SQL toolbelt. Also particularly canonical; windows have been in since SQL Server 2005.

Below is an example:

```
SELECT
    [From],
    DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, [To]) [To],
    payload
FROM (
    SELECT
        dt,
        MIN(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) [From],
        dt [To],
        SUM(payload) OVER(ORDER BY dt ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) payload
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, dt), 0) dt,
            SUM(payload) payload
        FROM #tmstmp
        GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, dt), 0)
    ) q
) q
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [From], [To]) > 3
```

I'd like to draw attention to both the `4 PRECEDING` and `DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, dt), 0)`. As the later practically floors the datetime to the minute, `2024-01-01 12:04:00.000` is inclusive up to `2024-01-01 12:04:59.999`, but doesn't include `2024-01-01 12:05:00.000`. Hopefully that's the functionality you are looking for.

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0aIGVBfs)

Comment: Great (+1), thats what I though that a window function may be the solution (hence the addded tag). How would I a adapt your code such that also the intervals at the end (which do not contain 5 full minutes) are included? The last interval from your code is `12:10-12:15` while mine also includes the `12:14-12:19` interval (last data point is `12:14:xx`?

Comment: Apologies for the untimely reply! You could switch the window clause to use `FOLLOWING` and then completely negate the "To" field. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S6fs0_As)